# Evaluate a List until a certain time has passed

Tags: haskell

I have a List whose (lazy) values take some time to compute. I would like to have a function that computes as many of those values as possible until a certain time passes.

I imagine a Signature like

```
computeUntil :: [a] -> Int -> IO ([a],[a])
computeUntil list seconds = (computedValues, uncomputedValues)
```

The details don't really matter. What's important, is that I can access anything in the first list of the result without delay.